# Can harddrives destroy motherboards/bioses?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, motherboard, bios, virus

I have a PC that went from bad to worse.  It started with harddrives problems that were not treated, and then the memory went bad according to a memtest.  Now, the motherboard won't work.

I moved the harddrive to a new machine that was working wonderfully, and immediately after I plugged it in, it gave me a "Detecting floppy drive A media... Drive A error.  System halt" error (Award BootBlock Bios v1.0).

This machine was in excellent condition and just bricked as soon as I plugged the faulty hdd in.  So, is it possible that the hdd has some kind of virus or structural flaw that causes it to destroy motherboards?

Update: the powersupply had been faulty, and the motherboard eventually popped.  The machine probably was not in excellent condition, initially, as previously stated.  Consequentially, I would have never discovered these problems if it weren't for the comments tied to the answer below.

Comment: It's possible but I seriously doubt it

Comment: Building/wall power bad? Lots of static / van de graff generators? Do you have shag carpet & thick socks, and shuffle everywhere? And does the "new machine" still work fine after removing the questionable hard drive?

Comment: The issue you're experiencing is caused by corrupted BIOS or UEFI firmware. Recovering from this condition requires reflashing the firmware; I'm not familiar with this process but it seems you'll need to have a floppy disk or optical disc with a BIOS image. (Some boards allow reflashing from a USB flash drive formatted as FAT32, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - it is possible, but highly unlikely.

As far as viruses go, it's still kind of conspiracy that bios malware especially UEFI is in the wild, actually it's the other way around HDD protected area is used for malware via vendor specific ATA commands, but that is still something that is not very much used in the wild and you can find such technology only in specific targeted attacks.

It sound more like bad PSU on the first PC, but using it on second one and bricking it too may be evidence of HDD mainboard failure that is returning voltage via the molex/SATA power cable and making voltage spikes, still most newer motherboards do have some sort of protection against such.

Your best course of action is to use external case on USB to download your data from that drive and use it as external if there are no problems, or you can try to measure for return voltage and if that is true than you can probably sue the HDD manufacturer for damages ( if you are in some good country ).

Comment: Yeah, well this PC is a bit newer (later than 2000, using DDR4 ram but still no PCI-E slot, so I dunno exactly).  I think the protection may have been to clear the bios?  I dunno, but I definitely want to fix it if it's possible because it's a great motherboard with a cooling fan on the bus and everything. :'(

Comment: Let's go about repairing the second one.. Remove the HDD that you talk about. Find the RST CMOS jumper on the motherboard ( or post exact model, so i can help ), Reset CMOS, / + Remove all DDR modules and start it once without any RAM / If you have more than 1 sticks of RAM, use only 1 in the closest to CPU socket, better yet if you have another RAM module that you know is working fine use that just for the test. Try to power the PC. If it goes thru POST / Boots / make a memtest cd and test your RAM.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, man.  I hope that works out.  I forgot all about the reset button.  I believe the RAM I'm using now is good.  It's fresh-new.

Comment: New not equ good :D Actually faulty devices are usually brand new, old and used ones tend to just 'die' - stop working at all, while new ones may give strange and hard to troubleshoot problems. Test it just to be sure, type 'memory' in Windows search and use the integrated Windows Memory Diagnostic ( Win 7 ) if you don't want to burn cd.

Comment: http://www.elhvb.com/supportbios.info/Archives/MANUAL/ABIT/ic7-g.pdf trying to find the nodes to reset the bios.

Comment: Page 2-7 CMOS Memory Clearing Header [CCMOS1] - Behind the IDE ports, right next to SATA ports.. short pins 2-3

Comment: Update: doing the CCMOS1 to pins 1 and 2 with the battery out just resulted in the same screen.  Next, I'm going to try booting to a floppy drive that has a new bios on it.

Comment: You must short pins 2 and 3, if there is a jumper cap then move it to 2-3 and then back or take something metal and short them for a bit. You can also take the big round battery out ( then pull the power cord for a minute or so ), remove all the memory modules and try to start it once that way - it wont start, but will clear the CMOS ( most cases ), then put back the battery and memory in.

Comment: If you can find a FDD that would be the best case. Create a bootable floppy, copy all files from the new BIOS on it ( it's distributed in exe file, but you can unpack it via 7zip ). When it boots run runme.bat. I found BIOS download here: http://drivers.hu/drv/abit/alaplap/drvhu_01-15_ic728.exe

Comment: Doing great.  Now the BIOS is loading up properly, and I'm getting a flashing screen (see update).